# Cual es la diferencia entre public, private, y no tener modificador de acceso en una variable

Tags: java

Cual es la diferencia en JAVA entre declarar una variable:

```
public String texto;
private String texto;
String texto
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 17):

En el código Java, las declaraciones de clase y variable y de método y constructor pueden tener "especificadores o modificadores de acceso", que pueden ser:

- `public`
- `private`
- `protected`
- ninguno

Los modificadores de nivel de acceso determinan si otras clases pueden usar un campo en particular o invocar un método en particular. Su efecto es diferente cuando se usa en clases, variables de clase, métodos de clase, constructores de clase.

Hay dos niveles de control de acceso:

- En el nivel superior: `public`, o `package-private` (sin modificador explícito).
- En el nivel de miembro: public, private, protected o `package-private` (paquete privado, cuando no se indica un modificador explícito).

## En el nivel superior

Una clase puede ser declarada con el modificador `public`, en cuyo caso esa clase es visible para todas las clases en todas partes. Si una clase no tiene ningún modificador (el valor predeterminado, también conocido como paquete-privado), sólo es visible dentro de su propio paquete (los paquetes se denominan [grupos de clases relacionadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)).

## En el nivel miembro

También se puede utilizar el modificador `public` o ningún modificador (paquete-privado) igual que en las clases de nivel superior y con el mismo significado.

Para los miembros, hay dos modificadores de acceso adicionales: `private` y `protected`. El modificador privado especifica que sólo se puede acceder al miembro en su propia clase. El modificador protegido especifica que el miembro sólo se puede acceder dentro de su propio paquete (como con package-private) y, además, por una subclase de su clase en otro paquete.

La siguiente tabla muestra el acceso a los miembros permitido por cada modificador:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Especificador     |   Clase   | SubClase  |  Paquete  |    Todos  |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
| public           |     sí    |    sí     |     sí    |    sí     |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
| private          |     sí    |    no     |     no    |    no     |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
| protected        |     sí    |    sí     |     sí    |    no     |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
| no declarado     |     sí    |    no     |     sí    |    no     |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Algunos ejemplos

### Ejemplo con variables de clase y  métodos de clase

Si consideramos este código:

```
class A {
    int x = 8;
}
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.x);
    }
}
```

El código compila y ejecuta. Pero, si  `int x` se declara `private`, entonces habrá un error de compilador ya que x tiene acceso privado en A. Esto se debe a que cuando una variable de miembro es privada, sólo se puede acceder dentro de esa clase.

### Especificadores de acceso para constructores

Los constructores pueden tener los mismos especificadores de acceso utilizados para variables y métodos. Su significado es el mismo. Por ejemplo, cuando un constructor ha sido declarado `private`, entonces, sólo la clase en sí puede crear una instancia de la misma (tipo de auto-referencia similar). Otra clase en el mismo paquete no puede crear una instancia de esa clase. Ni ninguna subclase de esa clase. Ni ninguna otra clase fuera de este paquete.

(Nota: los constructores en Java se tratan de manera diferente a los métodos. Los miembros de la clase son las variables de la clase y los métodos de la clase. Los constructores NO se consideran un miembro de la clase.)

Veamos un ejemplo de código:

```
class A {
    public int x;
    private A (int n) {
        x=n;
        System.out.println("Ok");
    }
}

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(7);
        System.out.println(a.x);
    }
}
```

En el código anterior habrá un error de compilación porque el constructor de `A` es `private` pero está siendo creado fuera de sí mismo. Si se elimina la palabra clave "`private`" delante del constructor de A, el error de compilación desaparece.

### Constructores de la misma clase pueden tener diferentes especificadores de acceso

Como ya sabemos, una clase puede tener más de un constructor, cada uno con parámetros diferentes. Cada constructor puede tener igualmente especificadores de acceso diferentes.

En el ejemplo siguiente, la clase `A` tiene dos constructores, uno toma un argumento `int`, el otro toma un argumento `double`. Uno se declara `private`, mientras que el otro no tiene especificador de acceso (acceso predeterminado a nivel de paquete).

```
class A {
    A (int n) {
        System.out.println("int Ok");
    }
    private A (double d) {
        System.out.println("double Ok");
    }
}

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A(5);
        //A a2 = new A(10.50);
    }
}
```

El hecho de que puede haber constructores con diferentes especificadores de acceso significa que en Java, la capacidad de crear un objeto también depende del constructor que se llama para crear el objeto.

### Especificadores de acceso para clases

Para las clases, sólo se puede utilizar el especificador de acceso `public`. Básicamente, Java tiene este paradigma "una Clase por archivo". Es decir, en cada archivo de código fuente de Java, sólo una clase en el archivo es accesible al público y esa clase debe tener el mismo nombre que el archivo. (Por ejemplo, si el archivo es `A.java`, entonces debe haber una clase llamada "`A`" en él, y esa es la clase que es pública). Opcionalmente, la clase se puede declarar usando la  palabra clave `public`.

Si se utiliza cualquier otro especificador de acceso en clases, o se declara más de una clase `public` en un archivo, el compilador se quejará. Para más detalles sobre esto se puede consultar [Paquetes en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

---

Fuentes:

- Documentación de Java: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 6):

Cuando defines una variable:

> - ***public***. Puedes acceder a la misma desde cualquier lugar del código.
> - ***private***. Solo puedes acceder dentro de la misma clase.
> - Si no declaras un modificador de acceso por defecto, será ***default*** y podrás acceder a nivel del package

Más información acerca de los dos últimos mencionados:

> https://sekthdroid.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/modificador-de-acceso-protected-y-default-en-java/

Answer (score 3):

Los modificadores de acceso limitan el acceso de las `variales, metodos, clases o interfaces` que la utilicen. El funcionamiento es el mismo en todos los casos, por lo que solo me referiré a las variables.

#### public

En los proyectos se utilizan paquetes para organizar las clases. Al declarar una variable como `public` esta podrá ser accedida desde cualquier clase del proyecto, ya sea que este en otro paquete o en el mismo.

#### Sin modificadores de acceso

Las variables declaradas sin un modificador de acceso solo podrá ser accedida desde las clases que estén en el mismo paquete que ella.

#### private

Las variables declaradas con este modificador de acceso solo podrán ser accedidas desde las clase donde es declarada.

## Ejemplo

La `Clase1` y la `Clase2` pertenecen al mismo paquete por lo que ambas podrán acceder a todas las variables que no sean privadas.

#### Clase1

```
proyecto.paquete1;

public class Clase1 {

    public String hola;
    String nombre;
    private String edad;

}
```

#### Clase2

```
proyecto.paquete1;

public class Clase2 {

    Clase1 clase1 = new Clase1();
    clase1.hola;
    clase1.nombre;
    // No puede acceder a la variable edad, ya que esta es privada y solo
    // solo puede ser accedida desde la clase donde se declaro.

}
```

#### clase3

```
proyecto.paquete2;

public class Clase3 {

    Clase1 clase1 = new Clase1();
    clase1.hola;
    // no puede acceder a la variable nombre, ya que no es publica y solo
    // puede ser accedida desde clase que se encuentren en el mismo paquete
    // donde esta fue declarada.

    // No puede acceder a la variable edad, ya que esta es privada y solo
    // solo puede ser accedida desde la clase donde se declaro.

}
```