# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un método privado desde otra clase en java?

Tags: java

Tengo dos clases en una tengo un atributo privado y un método privado pero necestio desde otra clase utilizar ese atributo privado al igual que el método

Comment: soy novato. Creo, y ya me corregirán, que para acceder a un atributo privado desde otra clase, se puede hacer algún método accesor tipo Get/Set.
Sobre el acceso al método privado, supongo que la pregunta es porqué es privado, y si está en el mismo paquete.
A ver que opinan los que saben!

Comment: Yo también soy novato, pero creo que si tiene 2 clases, hasta que no crees un objeto que derive de una clase, no podrás acceder a sus métodos. Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es acceder a los métodos y atributos de una clase heredada usa extends. https://javadesdecero.es/poo/herencia-java-tipos-ejemplos/

Comment: Deberías agregar un [mcve]

Comment: Hola Gabo Music, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre Stack Overflow (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para añadir más detalles: muestra el código que tienes, cómo intentas acceder al método de una clase desde la otra, los mensajes de error que estés recibiendo, etc. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 3):

Para poder usar el metodo desde otra clase primero necesitas instanciar la clase y los metodos **necesariamente** deben de estar en modo público si quieres utilizarlos desde objetos que sean de otras clases. Si defines un método como privado, sólo los objetos que sean de la misma clase a la que pertenece el método van a poder utilizarlo.

```
public class alumno {
    //atributos
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    //metodos Get y Set

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return this.edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombreParametro){
        this.nombre = nombreParametro;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edadParametro){
        this.edad = edadParametro;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class clase{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //instanciamos la clase
        alumno alumno = new alumno();
        //utilizamos sus metodos públicos
        alumno.setNombre("Alejandro");
        alumno.setEdad(18);

        System.out.println("Alumno: "+alumno.getNombre()+"\nEdad: "+alumno.getEdad());
    }
}
```

En esta respuesta explican un poco más acerca de los modificadores de acceso:  [modificadores de acceso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102213/156982)