# Kotlin - Porqué no se coloca private en los atributos con get() y set() de Backing Fields

Tags: kotlin

Si programamos los getters y setters se declararían así:

```
class Persona {
    private var nombre: String = ""

    fun setNombre(nombre: String) {
        this.nombre = nombre
    }

    fun getNombre(): Int {
        return this.nombre
    }

}
```

Pero kotlin nos permite usar [Backing Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields), haciendo que nuestros getters y setters queden de la siguiente forma:

```
class Persona {
    var nombre: String = ""
        set(value) {
           field = value
        }
        get() = field
}
```

Si se instancia la clase y uso los métodos getter y setter de la siguiente forma:

```
val persona = Persona()
println(persona.nombre)
```

me marca un error cuando declaro la variable **private** usando backing fields.

Porqué no se coloca la palabra reservada `private` en los atributos, si el fin de los getters y setters es ser accesores a las variables privadas de la clases, al no poner private en los atributos no se están declarando como públicas?

Cuál sería el sentido de getters y setters en atributos públicos? o Acaso Kotlin hace los atributos privados por defecto cuando se agregan backing fields, porque tengo entiendo que por defecto los atributos son públicos a menos que los declaremos como `private`, `protected` o `internal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver.... en kotlin cuando tu creas una variable o constante tipica,

```
var variable1=1
val constante=1
```

o cuando recuperas el valor de las variables y constantes,debemos entender que el compilador esta usando los getters y setters por defecto, asignando  o recuperando el dato, aunque tu no lo especifiques.... pero kotlin ademas ,te permite crear este tipo de getter y setter personalizados aplicados sobre cada atributo (variable o constante) para realizar filtros en los atributos, como por ejemplo que un atributo no pueda guardar un valor mayor a 10

Piensa como se crea un constructor de una clase en java,donde tu si quieres puedes  crear un constructor personalizado en una clase y decirle como debe asignar los parametros de entrada a los atrbutos , o bien, no especificar ningun constructor y que la clase utilice el contructor por defecto...

Aunque tambien tengo que decirte que si quieres en kotlin,  tambien puedes utilizar el metodo tradicional de getter y setter que se utiliza en java, utilizando las funciones como getters y setters

Ahora bien , ¿ porque te da error?

estos getter y setters  "Backing Fields" , no actuan como metodos tradicionales , donde le especificas modificadores de visibilidad, sino que actuan como funciones internas y externas ( algo parecido a las inner class) , es decir que solo estan accesibles dentro del atributo y no fuera........ esto quiere decir aunque tu estos getter y setter no los pongas como privados , desde otra clase no podras acceder a ellos.. ya que su ambito de actuacion es solo dentro del atributo correspondiente.

Fijate que estos getters y setters personalizados "backing fields" se ejecutan solos automaticamente cuando tu haces la accion de guardar datos , o cuando intentas recuperar un dato  en la variable o contante, no hace falta indicarselo al compilador. Por lo tanto cuando tu quieres acceder a ellos desde otra clase o desde la misma clase , lo haces a traves del atributo correspondiente automaticamente. por lo tanto el modificador de visisibilidad que tendria valor en este caso seria el del atributo, y no el de los getters y setters

Answer (score 0):

El punto de los metodos SET y GET es ser utilizados por otras clases y por medio de ellos modificar los valores de las variables privadas.

Para que un método pueda ser llamado dese otra clase al instanciar la clase que lo contiene **debe** de estar en modo público ya que el modificador private solo concede el acceso a la clase que los contiene.

Te dejo este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102213/156982) que explica más a fondo los modificadores de acceso

```
public class alumno {
    //atributos
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    //constructor
    public alumno(){
        this.edad = 0;
        this.nombre = "";
    }

    //metodos Get y Set

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return this.edad;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombreParametro){
        this.nombre = nombreParametro;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edadParametro){
        this.edad = edadParametro;
    }
}

public class clase{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        alumno alumno = new alumno();

        alumno.setNombre("Alejandro");
        alumno.setEdad(18);

        System.out.println("Alumno: "+alumno.getNombre()+"\nEdad: "+alumno.getEdad());
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @alejandro00, entiendo los métodos get y set, pero no entiendo porque cuando se usa [Backing Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) en kotlin, los atributos de la clase no llevan la palabra reservada private.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la POO, las variables de instancia(V.I.) deben ser encapsulados y para acceder a ellos debemos usar los métodos o funciones que provee la misma clase. Todo esto se hace con el fin de cumplir con el proceso de validación de la variable de instancia(V.I.).

Este concepto se aplica en los diferentes lenguajes de programación. Y la forma dependerá del sintaxis del lenguaje.

Por ejemplo en Java. Debemos declarar las V.I. con el modificador de acceso private y declarar los métodos getter y setter.

```
public class MiClase {

    private int edad ;

    public void setEdad(int edad){
        if(edad > 18)
           this.edad = edad ;
        else
           edad = 0 ;
    }

    public int getEdad(){
        return edad ;
    }

}
```

Observe que si declaramos edad como public, un cliente de la clase MiClase puede acceder directamente a la variable edad y establecer cualquier valor sin pasar por el proceso de validación. Esto sucede a pesar que hemos declarado el getter y setter de edad. Por este motivo y de acuerdo a la sintaxis de Java debemos declarar las V.I. con el modificador private, para que los clientes usen los getter y setter. Y de esta forma se cumple con el encapsulamiento.

El lenguaje Kotlin tiene su propia sintaxis para cumplir con el encapsulamiento. La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
class MiClase(edad: Int) {

    var edad: Int = edad  // edad -> public
    
    set(edad) {
        if(edad > 18)
           field = edad // this.edad -> recursividad infinita
        else
           field = 0 // edad = 0 -> recursividad infinita
    }

    get() {
        // return edad -> recursividad infinita
        return field
    }

}
```

En este ejemplo de Kotlin, cualquier cliente de MiClase nunca va a poder acceder directamente a la variable edad. A pesar de que edad es public. El cliente siempre va acceder al set() y get() de la variable edad. Por ejemplo:

```
fun main(){

    val objeto = MiClase(23) // edad = 23
    objeto.edad = 5 // se llama a set() y se valida -> edad = 0
    println(objeto.edad) // se llama a get() -> return edad = 0

}
```

Cada vez que se utiliza el nombre de la variable edad, kotlin llama a su get() y set() dependiendo del caso. De esta forma se cumple con el encapsulamiento. Los clientes de la clase siempre estarán OBLIGADOS a usar los setter y setter. En Java para obligar a los clientes a usar los get y set tenías que declarar la V.I. como private. En Kotlin no es necesario.

En el ejemplo MiClase de Kotlin observe que se usa la palabra clave "field", en vez de "this.edad" o "edad". Esto se hace para no tener el problema de recursividad infinita. Ya que si usáramos el nombre de la variable "edad" en  su mismo set() o get(), estaríamos llamando a su set() o get() en si mismo. Para no tener el problema de la recursividad infinita, Kotlin nos recomienda usar la palabra clave field.