# ¿Modificador de acceso "protected" no funciona bien aplicando herencia y polimorfismo en JAVA?

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo, access-control

estoy tratando de entender porque no funciona correctamente el modificador de acceso "protected" cuando aplico herencia y polimorfismo en 2 clases que estan en distinto paquete, expongo la situación:

Superclase:

```
package paquete1;

public class Acc {
    int p=1;
    private int q=2;
    protected int r=3;
    public int s=4;
    
}
```

Subclase:

```
package paquete2;
import paquete1.Acc;

public class Test extends Acc{
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Acc obj = new Test();

        System.out.println(obj.r);
        System.out.println(obj.s);
    }
    
}
```

El primer print me da error de compilación, me dice que el modificador de acceso para r es protected y que no tengo acceso, pero no entiendo por que.

La referencia "obj" es del tipo "Acc" que es la superclase y apunta a un objeto de tipo Test, que es la subclase ¿No deberia funcionar?

Y para mas confusión, si cambio el tipo de referencia al de la subclase, entonces SI que funciona, compila y me deja acceder sin problemas al atributo r.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias!

Comment: Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102213/29967) puede arrojar un poco de luz a tu duda. Dado que la propiedad es `protected` no puedes acceder a ella **desde otro paquete** usando su clase ( `Acc`)  pero sí a través de la sub-clase `Test`. El hecho es que si lo piensas bien, no tiene ningún sentido declarar en `Test` un objeto del tipo `Acc` siendo que `Test` extiende de `Acc`. Es totalmente ilógico hacer lo que haces en tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modificador `protected` especifica que sólo se puede acceder al miembro desde dentro de su propio paquete o por una subclase en otro paquete.

Dicho esto, la clase `Test` está en otro paquete, entonces si haces `Acc obj = new Test();`, no podrás acceder a su atributo `r` con `obj.r`, pero si podras acceder internamente, pero si lo haces en el main no te dejará porque es `static` y las variables `r` y `s` no lo son.

Solución 1:

```
package paquete2;

import paquete1.Acc;

public class Test extends Acc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    
    public void foo() {
        // Accedes internamente desde un metodo non-static (porque r y s no lo son)
        // No es necesario el super 
        System.out.println(super.r);
        System.out.println(super.s);
    }    
}
```

Solución 2:

```
package paquete2;

import paquete1.Acc;

public class Test extends Acc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // En vez de que sea de tipo Acc que sea Test
        // Al ser el objeto de tipo Test si está en el mismo paquete
        Test obj = new Test();
        System.out.println(obj.r);
        System.out.println(obj.s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, creo que toda mi confusion ha sido porque daba por hecho que "obj" era de tipo Test debido a que apunta a un objeto de tipo Test, pero realmente "obj" es de tipo Acc, gracias!

Comment: @MrDave1999 Dicho y hecho, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

La documentación del *modificador* [protected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) dice lo siguiente:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

**Traducción a español:**

> El modificador protegido especifica que solo se puede acceder al miembro dentro de su propio paquete (como un package-private) y además, por una subclase de su clase en otro paquete.

Esto quiere decir dos cosas:

**1.-** No podrás acceder al miembro **r** de la clase `Acc` porque está en otro paquete.

**2.-** La clase `Test` si podrá acceder al miembro **r** porque lo heredó de la clase `Acc`.

Respondiendo a estas preguntas:

> > El primer print me da error de compilación, me dice que el modificador de acceso para r es protected y que no tengo acceso, pero no entiendo por que.

Da error de compilación porque la clase `Test` se encuentra en otro paquete. Para solucionar el error de compilación, debes añadir la clase `Test` en el paquete donde esté la clase `Acc`.

> > La referencia "obj" es del tipo "Acc" que es la superclase y apunta a un objeto de tipo Test, que es la subclase ¿No deberia funcionar?

Claro, funcionaría si la clase `Test` estuviera en el mismo paquete donde está `Acc`.

> > Y para mas confusión, si cambio el tipo de referencia al de la subclase, entonces SI que funciona, compila y me deja acceder sin problemas al atributo r.

Claro, funciona porque la clase `Test` si puede tener acceso al miembro **r** (sin importar que esté en distinto paquete) porque lo heredó de la clase `Acc`.

Comment: Gracias @MrDave1999, todo esto ha pasado porque me estoy iniciando en la POO y aun tengo un poco de confusión con el tema de las referencias y los objetos a los que apuntan, "obj" es una referencia de tipo Acc, no de tipo Test, por tanto las normas de acceso aplican al ripo de la referencia, no al tipo de objeto al que apunta la misma, ¿Esta bien así?

Comment: @tHe_sHayKo La *norma de acceso* va aplicado en este caso al miembro `r` de la clase `Acc`, no tiene nada que ver con el **tipo de la referencia** `obj` o el **tipo del objeto**. Aquí la regla de acceso cae directamente al miembro (en este caso es un atributo de la clase `Acc`) que tenga el modificador *protected*.