# Se heredan atributos privados por medio de los super()?

Tags: java, poo, herencia, constructor

Cordial saludo
Espero que me puedan despejar mi duda si no es mucha molestia

Es claro que una subclase no  hereda atributos privados de una superclase, sin embargo esto es posible a traves de los super() ?

Anexo codigo para mejor comprension

```
class SuperClass { 
 private int n=3; 
 int getN() { 
  return n; 
 } 
} 

class SubClass extends SuperClass { 
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
  SubClass e = new SubClass(); 
  System.out.println("n= " + e.getN()); 
 }
```

Cuando corro main me sale la salida como n=3. Lo que parece que SubClass está heredando el atributo privado n de SuperClass.

El super del constructor de la subclase invoca al constructor de la superclase y en este constructor heredo los atributos privados?

Gracias :))

Comment: Lo que heredan las clases hijas de una clase padre son los métodos y atributos públicos y protegidos de sus clases padres, los métodos privados solo son accesibles para la clase a la que pertenecen.

Comment: Declaraste un getter público y eso es lo que te está dando acceso a la propiedad, por lo demás si un atributo es privado solo se alcanza dentro del scope de la clase que lo define

Comment: Ni `super()` ni los constructores te *autorizan* a nada. `super()` te permite invocar al constructor de la clase padre para pasarle aquellas propiedades que acaba de recibir la clase hija pero que están declaradas en la clase padre. Es como si dijeras: *esto es del padre y se lo paso con `super()`*. El acceso lo define la herencia en sí misma, según los modificadores de acceso de cada propiedad y depende de varios ámbitos, [como se explica aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102213/29967).

Comment: Gracias por responder  :)                                En efecto con super() invoco al constructor de la superclase y le paso los parametros que recibio la subclase. ¿Es decir que la subclase como tal si heredo esos atributos privados pero solo son accesibles desde la superclase atraves de los getters?                        Entonces se dice que no son heredados porque no se puede acceder a ellos desde su misma clase, me equivoco?. Muchas gracias que pena la molestia

Answer (score 1):

No. La clase hija no está heredando los atributos privados del padre. Lo que sí hereda son los métodos públicos y protegidos de la clase padre. Y esos métodos son los que tienen acceso a los atributos privados. Eso es encapsulación, una de las características de la programación orientada a objetos.

Mira un ejemplo de como la clase hija no puede modificar los atributos privados del padre, supongamos que la clase padre tiene un método `setN()`:

```
int setN(int n) {
    if (n > 100) n = 10;
    this.n = n;
}
```

La clase hija va a llamar ese método para cambiar el valor de `n` en la clase padre: `e.setN(200)`, pero fíjate en algo, el método `setN()` tiene una condición que si el número es mayor que 100 lo convertirá en 10, y luego viene la parte clave `this.n = n;`, `this` es la clase padre, solo el padre puede modificar sus valores.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código funciona así como está y no te da error al acceder al método de la clase base porque a ese método no le has especificado el modificador de acceso (`private`, `public`, `protected`). Al no hacer esto, se considera que tiene el modificador por defecto. Esto da acceso a nivel de `package`. Así que todas las clases de ese mismo `package` van a tener acceso a ese método. Así que te funciona, pero de suerte ;-)

Para definir bien tu clase base tendrías que escribir el método indicándole cómo quieres que se acceda a él desde las demás clases. El diseño de tus clases es cosa tuya.