# Llamar al método de una clase desde otra clase Java

Tags: java, poo

Tengo dos clases **A** y **B**, y quiero acceder desde A a un método de B, para ello, tendría que crear un objeto B en la clase de A y acceder al método:

```
private B b = new B();
b.nombreMétodo()
```

La pregunta es: en ese "b.", ¿le paso o le puedo pasar algún valor (el que le asigne el constructor) o ese objeto simplemente es para saber que quiero acceder a un método de la clase B y para ello uso un objeto de esa clase?
En el caso de que le pase o le pueda pasar algún valor, para qué serviría?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta no es del todo clara. Revisa si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102213/29967) ayuda a aclarar alguna duda que tengas. Si la duda persiste entonces sé más específico, haz pruebas con el código y dinos el problema que tienes exactamente.

Comment: A penas sé Java, estoy empezando poco a poco y no sé cómo expresarme mejor, mi duda en general es cómo utilizar el operador punto para acceder a métodos, variables...

Comment: Pues se utiliza tal cual lo has utilizado. No tiene más. En cuanto a *le paso o le puedo pasar algún valor* -> Si, puedes, igual que le pasas cosas en el constructor, los métodos también aceptan **parámetros**. Tu otra pregunta, *para qué serviría?* -> Pues... depende de lo que quieras hacer. Es que no hay respuesta *genérica* para esto. Un ejemplo muy sencilo: `public void greet(String nombre){System.out.println("Hola, " + nombre);}`, con un método así en tu clase podrías usar `b.greet("Pepito")` y saludaría a pepito.

Comment: En el [tutorial de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) está explicado lo del punto. En cuanto a pasar parámetros entre paréntesis, aparte de lo que te dice @Benito-B puedes consultar el [tutorial sobre los *argumentos*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) de la documentación.

Comment: En el método "nombreMetodo()" de b.nombreMetodo() sí que puedo pasarle parámetros, pero "b." tiene algún valor?

Comment: "b" es un objeto de clase B. Su valor es literalmente ser un objeto de esa clase... Si quieres que esa clase tenga otros valores dentro, tendrás que usar variables de clase. En el [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) que te ha enlazado el señor @A.Cedano tienes ejemplos de cómo hacer eso. Este tipo de dudas como mejor las vas a poder resolver es *cacharreando* y si luego tienes alguna duda más específica/concreta/que no puedes resolver, aquí siempre estamos :)

Comment: El [Tutorial de Java también explica lo que sería `b` en tu caso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). Si analizas el código, `b` se creó haciendo una llamada a `new B ()`. El tutorial explica lo que ocurre en ese caso: ***El  operador `new` crea una instancia de una clase asignando memoria para un nuevo objeto y devolviendo una referencia a ese espacio en memoria. El operador `new` también invoca al constructor de objetos.*** Podríamos decir que `b` es una instancia de la clase `B` y que deberías poder usar todos sus métodos y propiedades.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas!!

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar a método de la clase A en la clase B puedes:

- Crear una instancia de la clase A  desde la clase B y así poder acceder a sus métodos.
- Pasar el objeto A como [parámetro por referencia](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/parametros-por-referencia-en-java/), lo que sucede es que el parámetro copia la referencia hacia una instancia de la clase A.
- Utilizar Palabra Clave “[static](https://javadesdecero.es/palabra-clave/static/)” en el método que desees utilizar en otras clases, static también funciona para atributos. Puede acceder a los métodos de la clase A si necesidad de crear un objeto.